# "Mysql problem "profile data do not show in my html page

Tags: mysql, node.js, hbs

I am trying to view a data from Mysql and pass it to the profile page where i can see the info of the user but i tried many time and different ways but couldnt find a way and also there is no errors I used {{#each}}{{this.fullname}}{{/each}} i tired if also but the data does not display would anyone help me to pls to solve it or if there is another way to display my data

i am using node js, express and hbs engine

```
router.get('/profilePage/:userid', function(req, res) {

    var userid = req.params.userid;
    
    pool.query('SELECT * from users where id = ?', userid, function(error, results, feilds) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error ocurred while getting user details of " + userid, error);
            res.send({
                "code": 400,
                "failed": "error ocurred"
            });
        } else {
            res.render("profilePage",{user:results});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show the code of `profilePage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
router.get('/profilePage/:userid', function(req, res) {

    var userid = req.params.userid;
    if (!userid) {
     //No user id provided
     } else {
    pool.query('SELECT * from users where id = ?',
    [userid], 
   (error, results, feilds)=> {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error ocurred while getting user details of " + userid, error);
            res.send({
                "code": 400,
                "failed": "error ocurred"
            });
        } else {
            if (results.length > 0) {
            const profile = results[0]
            //You can then access the user id with
            console.log(profile.id)
            res.render("profilePage",{user:profile});
            } else {
             console.log('unable to retrieve a profile')
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: the code is working thank you so much, i would like to ask how can i display it inside my profilePage.hbs where i have for example <div>user info to be displayed here</div>

Comment: I'm not so familiar with handlebars but ill like to point you to [this tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-handlebars-templating-engine-for-node) . It's also important to note that all of your profile data are inside the profile object.  So, if you want to get the `first_name` It will be `user.first_name` etc.

Comment: thank you so much, your codes helped me a lot, i was able to fix the error and i was able to display the data on the page but i do have a little problem. right now if i want to access the userid i need to type for example http://localhost:3002/profilePage/75 what i want to do is i want to pull the id from express-session how can i do that, i tried to set it but i am missing something which is i do not know pls help me if you can. and thank you so much for the codes i am so thankfull for it

Comment: when your user logs in for the first time. you wan to store the userID  in the session by doing `req.session.userID = YOUR_USER_ID`  then you can always reference back to that logged in user by calling `const userID = req.session.userID` . Before this will work, ensure that you have followed [this setup guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Comment: i am getting error {"code":400,"failed":"error ocurred"}